# Начал обучаться Django, но не запускается сервер

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, сервер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается запустить сервер не понимаю в чем дело, пытаюсь открыть 127.0.0.1:8000 в браузере, но не удается получить доступ к сайту

```
C:\Users\Mikhail\Documents\working space\django-examples\mysite>python 
manage.py
 runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 13, 2018 - 15:29:07
Django version 2.0.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. 
<locals>.wrapper at 0x03213D20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper 
fn(*args,**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 142, in 
inner_run
ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 163, in run
httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 66, in __init__
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: 
invalid continuation byte
```

Про проблему с кирилицей в имени пользователя сразу подумал и изменил, однако на результат это никак не повлияло.
Версию питона я использую 3.6.5

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Нужно изменить не имя пользователя, а имя компьютера

Answer (score 0):

По собственной невнимательности и слепой уверенности в уникальности своих ошибок решил, что имя пользователя и имя компьютера это одно и то же.
Изменил имя компьютера, как посоветовали в комментариях, так проблема и решилась.
Спасибо